# How to prevent overwriting input IDs in an R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

### Goal

I want my app user to be able to create as many tabs in a tabset panel as they want. The inputs in each tab are identical, but their IDs need to be unique so that I can later use them for analysis.

### Shiny app

The following app works but the IDs are overwritten when a user creates a new tab.

#### Module

I have my module in the `R/` directory:

```
mod_part_A_ui <- function(id) {
 ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    # Button to launch a new event modal where the user provides the event name.
    actionButton(ns("add"), "New Event"),
    br(),
    br(),
    # A panel of tabs. Each tab corresponds to one event.
    tabsetPanel(id = ns("tabs")),

    verbatimTextOutput(ns("printt"))
  )
}

mod_part_A_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      ns <- session$ns

      # When the 'New Event' button is clicked, a modal pops up asking for event name.
      observeEvent(input$add, {
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            textInput(
              inputId = ns("event_name"),
              label = "Event name:",
              value = ""
            ),
            actionButton(ns("submit_event_name"), "Submit"),
            title = "Enter event name",
            footer = NULL,
            size = "s",
            easyClose = FALSE
          )
        )

      })

      # Enter the name and click the 'Submit' button which will close the modal
      ## and create a new tab with the same tab title as the event name.
      observeEvent(input$submit_event_name, {
        removeModal()

        # Event name and IDs
        event_name <- input$event_name
        text_area_id <- paste0(event_name, "_", "comments")
        save_btn_id <- paste0(event_name, "_", "save")

        insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
                  tabPanel(
                    title = event_name,
                    tagList(
                      br(),
                      layout_columns(
                        tagList(
                          lapply(
                            c("Func", "Hi", "Ta",
                              "Re", "En", "An", "Co",
                              "Aff", "Cr"),
                            function(x) {
                              div(
                                class = "btn-group-label",
                                span(class = "label-spacing", paste0(x, ":")),
                                radioGroupButtons(
                                  inputId = ns(paste0(event_name, "_", "radio_", gsub("\\s", "", x))),
                                  choiceNames = c("+", "-", "x"),
                                  choiceValues = c("present and positive",
                                                   "present and negative",
                                                   "not present"),
                                  status = "primary",
                                  size = "normal",
                                  selected = character(0)
                                )
                              )
                            }
                          )#,

                          # verbatimTextOutput("func")
                        ),

                        textAreaInput(inputId =  ns(text_area_id),
                                      label = "Notes:",
                                      placeholder = "Add your notes here.",
                                      width = "500px", height = "500px"),

                        col_widths = c(5, 7)
                      ),
                      actionButton( ns(save_btn_id), "Save")
                    )

                  )
        )
      })


      output$printt <- renderPrint({

        event_name <- input$event_name
        text_area_id <- paste0(event_name, "_", "comments")
        save_btn_id <- paste0(event_name, "_", "save")


        radio_values <- lapply( c("Func", "Hi", "Ta",
                              "Re", "En", "An", "Co",
                              "Aff", "Cr"), function(x) {
          input_id <- paste0(event_name, "_radio_", gsub("\\s", "", x))
          input_value <- input[[input_id]]
          return(paste0(x, ": ", input_value))
        })

        text_value <- input[[text_area_id]]
        save_value <- input[[save_btn_id]]

        list(radio_values, text_value, save_value)
      })

    }
  )
}
```

#### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bslib)

# UI

ui <- page_fluid(
 
  mod_part_A_ui("part_A")
)

# Server

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  mod_part_A_server("part_A")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you create two tabs, the `printt` output shows the inputs of the second tab in both tabs. How do I prevent overwriting input IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `input$tabs` instead of `input$event_name` to get the id of the selected tab, i.e. do (Note: I dropped the radio buttons for simplicity)

```
output$printt <- renderPrint({
  event_name <- input$tabs
  text_area_id <- paste0(event_name, "_", "comments")
  save_btn_id <- paste0(event_name, "_", "save")
  
  text_value <- input[[text_area_id]]
  save_value <- input[[save_btn_id]]
  
  list(text_value, save_value)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that I could just get the tab ID.